# Gatsby.js with Ghost CMS: How to query a list of post including same tags of current post

Tags: graphql, gatsby, ghost-blog

I wish to display a list of posts that are including the same tag/tags than the current post.
I cannot find a way to query the good information.

I am able to make this query with `graphiql` but not able to reproduce it as I want to replace the $slug variable.

```
  allGhostPost(filter: {tags: {elemMatch: {name: {eq: $slug }}}}) {
    nodes {
      title
      tags {
        name
      }
    }
  }
}
```

As I have access to my current post tags inside of the `post.js` file I would like to be able to replace $slug by a variable in my component like `post.tags.map(tag =>tag` but this doesn't seem to be possible.

Do you know a way?

Comment: I am using this [starter](https://github.com/TryGhost/gatsby-starter-ghost)

Answer (score 0):

You might benefit from checking out our GraphQL recipes in our docs, they might be good reference points for you: https://ghost.org/docs/api/v3/gatsby/graphql-recipes-for-ghost/

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to add a avriable in the query when looking for tags.
As tags is an array, if you want to filter out artciles exluding or including tags you can pass an array to your variable. But it is necessary to use the `[String]` scalar type and not `String`

Here is an example query

```
 likePosts: allGhostPost(
    limit: 3
    filter: {
      id: { ne: $id }
      published_at: { lt: $published_at }
      tags: { elemMatch: { slug: { in: $tags } } }
    }
    sort: { fields: published_at, order: DESC }
  ) {
    edges {
      node {
        title
        date: published_at(formatString: "DD MMM YYYY")
      }
    }
  }
```

When you use the `[String]` scalar type you have to use `in` or `nin` instead of `eq` or `ne`

```
tags: { elemMatch: { slug: { in: $tags } } }
```

Here we are looking for all post having the same tags

To test it out in graphiql in the `query variables` section we could add

```
{
  "id": "Ghost__Post__5f8809143f185d9a1c72c199",
  "published_at": "2020-10-15T08:32:21.000+00:00",
  "tags":["media-buying", "case-study"],
  "slug": "affiliate-media-buy-case-study-how-to-deal-with-very-large-scale-networks-2"
}
```

Here we pass an arry to the `tags` variable